# WordPress issue, with a link div and a theme background

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm a web development student, and I am helping a friend in adding some custom links and slider to her wordpress website. The thing is the developer who made her website 6 years ago didn't create a child theme and she agrees to not making any update

I need to add some links in the footer widgets, which i did, but i see that there is an image background to the container containing these widgets, is it safe if i just remove the background from the theme css file ? I mean as she isn't updating her theme nor website, can I achieve it by removing it by editing the theme CSS, 
ps sorry for my newbie question but can't find any ressource on this special question.

[it looks like this, there is a background on the div (i've put the same color on the smaller div)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEPyp.png) 
Thank you for your help and your time.

Comment: Sorry my Hello was deleted :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a best practice to edit the Parent theme CSS. Even if you do so when a new update comes it will all be overwritten(If you don't update your theme periodically you will be missing out on many security fixes). So it's best if you can create a child theme and update the changes there. Just change the current theme to your child theme it's just a one click action and will save you all your changes in the future. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand your question correctly, I'd say it's not safe to remove the background CSS from the theme's style.css (or whatever file it is using). The problem might be theme updates that'll overwrite your changes.

So the best would be to create a child theme with a fews clicks, it's really easy:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

So you won't have to bother with updates.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the WordPress version you might have the Custom CSS Section within -> Appearance -> Customize - https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/ - Here you can just write your own CSS to overwrite the background of  the container.